# Grep and paste in the same file

Tags: xml, bash, grep, tags, synology

I have a file like this. I need to copy a specific tag into another tag and for each section where the tag is present.

```
<Idcode>123456</Idcode>
<DrctDbtTxInf>
  <InstrId>XXX</InstrId>
  <EndToEndId>XXX</EndToEndId>
  <InstdAmt Ccy="EUR">XXX</InstdAmt>
  <MndtId>XXX</MndtId>
  <DtOfSgntr>XXX</DtOfSgntr>
  <AmdmntInd>XXX</AmdmntInd>
  <Nm>XXX</Nm>
  <IBAN>XXX</IBAN>
  <Ustrd>XXX</Ustrd>
</DrctDbtTxInf>
<DrctDbtTxInf>
  <InstrId>XXX</InstrId>
  <EndToEndId>XXX</EndToEndId>
  <InstdAmt Ccy="EUR">XXX</InstdAmt>
  <MndtId>XXX</MndtId>
  <DtOfSgntr>XXX</DtOfSgntr>
  <AmdmntInd>XXX</AmdmntInd>
  <Nm>XXX</Nm>
  <IBAN>XXX</IBAN>
  <Ustrd>XXX</Ustrd>
</DrctDbtTxInf>
```

and I would have a result like this:

```
<Idcode>123456</Idcode>
<DrctDbtTxInf>
  <Idcode>123456</Idcode>
  <InstrId>XXX</InstrId>
  <EndToEndId>XXX</EndToEndId>
  <InstdAmt Ccy="EUR">XXX</InstdAmt>
  <MndtId>XXX</MndtId>
  <DtOfSgntr>XXX</DtOfSgntr>
  <AmdmntInd>XXX</AmdmntInd>
  <Nm>XXX</Nm>
  <IBAN>XXX</IBAN>
  <Ustrd>XXX</Ustrd>
</DrctDbtTxInf>
<DrctDbtTxInf>
  <Idcode>123456</Idcode>
  <InstrId>XXX</InstrId>
  <EndToEndId>XXX</EndToEndId>
  <InstdAmt Ccy="EUR">XXX</InstdAmt>
  <MndtId>XXX</MndtId>
  <DtOfSgntr>XXX</DtOfSgntr>
  <AmdmntInd>XXX</AmdmntInd>
  <Nm>XXX</Nm>
  <IBAN>XXX</IBAN>
  <Ustrd>XXX</Ustrd>
</DrctDbtTxInf>
```

Considering the limit of my bash version: 4.4.23(1)-release.

Thanks for any help!

I tried to seach a topic like this but it's also complicated to search it

Comment: Try to [improve your question](/help/how-to-ask) please. Be more specific about the problem and also fix the posted samples indentation for readability.

Comment: update the question to explicitily state which tag(s) you're looking to modify and with what content; as is currently written we have to scroll up/down the two sections of data trying to figure out what's changed ... nope, ain't happenin' here ...

Comment: Guys sorry…I’ll try to be clearer: what I need is to take the tag <Idcode>123456</Idcode> that is into the file my.xml and copy inside the tag <DrctDbtTxInf> for all occurrences of <DrctDbtTxInf> into the same file my.xml…I hope it’s clearer now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the task:

1. **grep** does not help much, you find the *Idcode* and *DrctDbtTxInf* lines, but then you are pretty stuck
2. **paste** is not helpful at all (I think).  Paste is used to merge entire files
3. I think you could be successful just using **sed**, but that would be perverse
4. I believe that a shell script using most any shell would work, and not be that difficult (if you are up on your shell scripting)
5. Here is a one-liner using gawk (awk) that is probably shorter than a shell equivalent:

   gawk '{print}/**<Idcode>/{sub(/**/,"");I=$0}/<DrctDbtTxInf>/{print I}' < ourInputFile

- read next line & print it
- if the line matches **<Idcode>, chop off asterisks and name result **I**
- if the line matches <DrctDbtTxInf>, print **I**